# change error messages after form validation in Magento

Tags: validation, forms, magento

how can i change the error message Magento throws after it validates the form? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found it at

.../js/prototype/validation.js

there's a list of the conditions and the error message that corresponds to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the error message on the fly inside your validation function using this.error="custom message"

```
['validate-zip-extra', 'Please enter a valid zip code', function (v) {
        v = v.trim();
        this.error = "custom validation error extra";
        var regexpString = /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9](\s)?([a-z]{2})$/i;
        return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || regexpString.test(v);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}],
```